# Inserting a page Break in a text file by inserting FormFeed Character. Is this Universal solution?

Tags: java, character-encoding, notepad, printers, page-break

Inserting a page Break in a text file by inserting FormFeed Character using Java.

Is my solution universal or will it cause any problems?

```
Sample Code:
PrintWriter bof = response.getWriter();             // Obtained Writer from HTTP Response
bof.write("Para 1");                        // Write 1st Para to printWriter
bof.write(new Character((char) 12).toString());         // Write Form Feed Character for Page Break
bof.write("Para 1");                        // Write 2nd Para to printWriter
```

My Concerns: The **Solution is working** but below my 2 concenrs:

Point 1: Is there a way to hide Unknown symbol shown for FormFeed character in notepad ?

Point 2: 
I am currently opening the txt file with Word and checking the print Preview:

the Form Feed is actually making a page break as expected.

But are there any implications to this solution or will it work universally with all printers?

Comment: AFAIK, FormFeed should work with almost every printer, as long as you are printing in text mode. For text editors, though, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Can you explain the problems we may face with text editors ..

Comment: Well, different text editors will handle formfeed differently (if at all); some may handle it as a page break, some may handle it as a newline, some may show the character explicitly, some may not show it at all. Printers do handle it somewhat consistently, though. Do you need the text to be editable?

Comment: @  Haroldo_OK

`When txt file is opened by Notepad:
    Display: Form Feed character is explicitly shown as a symbol.`


    `On Printing it: the Unreadable symbol is printed and page Break is not coming as expected.`

Comment: `When txt file is opened by MS Word Program:`


     `Display: Form Feed character is invisible and in print preview also its rendered as Page Break.`

    `On Printing: FormFeed character is invisible on page and pageBreak happened as expected.`

Comment: `Problem is I need the Same behavior of MS Word in NotePad also.` 
`By Default my txt file is obtained in ANSI Encoding and ANSI doesnt contain FormFeed character(12) in it.`
`Is this the reason why FF is shown as unreadable symbol ?`
How to solve this any idea ? How do i resolve this problem ?

Comment: So, basically: if you send it directly to the printer, without opening it on a text editor, it will work; if you open it on a text editor and then ask the text editor to print it, your mileage will vary.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK : Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Factors effecting Display and Print:**

`Display` of formFeed on opening a txt file by a program depends on:

- The Program's Interpretation of FormFeed character.

But `Print operation` result depends on:

- Program used to open and Print txt file
- The Printer we are using.

**Form Feed Character handling by Various Programs:**

`1)NotePad:`

- Notepad is only text Editor and dont interpret Form Feed Character as
  pageBreak.
- Hence when a txt file containing a formFeed Character:

  when opened with Notepad >> It is displayed as Unreadable Symbol

  When Printed after opening with NotePad : same unreadable Symbol is
  printed on paper.

2) Some `WordProcessors like WordPad/ Microsoft Word`/other 3rd party Editors :

- Renders FormFeed character correctly as pageBreak.
- On opening txt file with them Displays it as pageBreak and on
  printing also it acts as pagebreak.
- We can also see Form Feed rendered as PageBreak in PrintPreview
  option in programs like WordPag/MS Word.

**Universal Solution for getting PageBreak:**

- Some printers dont support Page Break by formFeed character and
  simply **Ignores it** irrespective of program used to open/print it.
- Usage of `"/page" with RichTextFile(RTF) File  is more Reliable/Universal
  solution` and works with most printers.

**With Rtf Files we can specify:**

- "/page" instead of "/f" for page Break and /par for lineBreak.
- Rtf file is opened by default with Wordpad program in Windows.
- `Additional format control is possible` using Rtf file like:

  **ex:** particular font and font size (like Times New Roman size 10)
  can be specified.

**In my Case Solution used is:**

Point 1:

- when opened by notepad Unreadable symbol is shown as notepad cant
  render FormFeed character.

Point 2:

- I got PageBreak in Print Preview as I used MS Word which renders
  formFeed correctly as Page Break.
- But as already said some Printers might ignore it eventhough MS Word
  interprets it correctly and sends it for printing.

So I used **rtf file instead of txt file** and hence used "/page" instead of "/f" for more universal solution.

- Below Hyperlink specifies info on how to create Rtf file and use
  /apge for page Break:

  [rtf File creation and using it for font and page Break Features](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/chr-12-form-feed-in-notepad.711862/)