# Why FormFeed Character in a txt File is rendered as Page Break by MS Word / WordPad but not by NotePad?

Tags: character-encoding, ms-word, notepad, page-break, wordpad

I have a .txt file and it has FormFeed character between para1 and para 2.

Para2 needs to be shown in next page on printing hence FormFeed is placed here.

```
sample txt file layout:
para1
formFeedCharacter
para2
```

`expected layout on printing:`

para1 is shown in 1st page and para 2 is shown in 2nd page as formFeed **acts as page break.**

`When opened and printed with` **MS Word/WordPad**:

expected layout is coming in 2 pages as expected.

`When opened and printed with` **NotePad**:

1)FormFeed is not acting as Page Break and all content is printed in 1 page only

2)FormFeed is displayed as unreadable Symbol

```
Final Printed layout when used Notepad:

para1

Unreadable symbol   (caused by FormFeed)

para2
```

Why Notepad is unable to render FormFeed as pageBreak ?

Is it because NotePad is a text Editor While WordPad/MS Word is Word processor ?

Is there any way how we can make this work with NotePad ?

Comment: It appears Notepad simply does not support the concept of "page break". If you search the Internet (Google, for example) you'll find a number of discussions where this is confirmed.

Comment: @Cindy : Thanks. you are correct ! Notepad dont support Page Break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notepad:**

1)It is a text Editor program and cannot interpret Form Feed character as Page Break.

2) Hence there is no way we can make formFeed work as page break and print it by using NotePad.

**WordPad/MS Word:**

1) Both are Word Processor softwares and can interpret FormFeed correctly as Page Break.
 Hence Unreadable symbol is not shown on opening txt file with them

2) We can also see the page Break by Print Preview feature in wordpad/NotePad.

This hyperLink provides additional information on this topic:
[Additional Info](http://forums.devshed.com/visual-basic-programming-52/text-file-formfeed-print-page-282511.html)

Also below hyperlink shows similar topic post asking for a universal solution for pageBreak Feature using txt file.

[page Break in txt file Universal Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407896/inserting-a-page-break-in-a-text-file-by-inserting-formfeed-character-is-this-u)

Comment: Archived version of the "Additional Info" link (which now just leads to a 404): https://web.archive.org/web/20170319183920/http://forums.devshed.com/visual-basic-programming-52/text-file-formfeed-print-page-282511.html